How to implement openAI API?
When I run this :
import os
import openai
openai.api_key = "my_api_key"

messages = [
    {"role": "system", "content": "You're a recruiter who asks tough interview questions"}
]

while True:
    content = input("User: ")
    messages.append({"role": "user", "content": content})

    completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
      model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages=messages
    )

    chat_response = completion.choices[0].message.content
    print(f'ChatGPT: {chat_response}')

I get this return:

APIRemovedInV1:
You tried to access openai.ChatCompletion, but this is no longer
supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at
https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API.
You can run openai migrate to automatically upgrade your codebase to
use the 1.0.0 interface.
Alternatively, you can pin your installation to the old version, e.g.
pip install openai==0.28
A detailed migration guide is available here:
https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742

I tried this:
import os
import openai
openai.api_key = "my_api_key"

messages = [
    {"role": "system", "content": "You're a recruiter who asks tough interview questions"}
]

while True:
    content = input("User: ")
    messages.append({"role": "user", "content": content})

    completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
      model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages=messages
    )

    chat_response = completion.choices[0].message.content
    print(f'ChatGPT: {chat_response}')

I would rather have seen the answer of ChatGPT

Does this answer your question? OpenAI API error: "You tried to access openai.ChatCompletion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0"


Uninstall the OpenAI library and then reinstall it to the latest version.
Give this code a try:

from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI(api_key = "YOUR API KEY HERE")

message_history = [{"role": "system", "content": "you are a helpful assistant"}]

def gpt_response():

    response = client.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo-1106",
    messages=message_history,
    temperature=0.9,
    max_tokens=500)

    return response.choices[0].message.content

user_response = "temp"

while user_response != "stop":
    
    bot_response = gpt_response()
    print("Bot Response : " , bot_response)
    
    message_history.append({"role" : "assistant" , "content" : bot_response})
    
    print("********************************************")

    user_response = input("User Response: ")
    print("Your Response: " , user_response)
    

    message_history.append({"role" : "user" , "content" : user_response})
    print("********************************************")


Using the below function, you can run openai key.
def generate(prompt): 
    response = openai.Completion.create( 
        engine="gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct", 
        prompt=f"Provide me the answer of {prompt}", 
        max_tokens=60, 
        n=1, 
        stop=None, 
        temperature=0.7, 
        ) 
    return response.choices[0].text.strip()

